# Publish custom endpoint address in ASP.NET Core minimal API

Tags: asp.net-core, endpoint, minimal-apis

I have 6 API methods as you can see:

```
app.MapGet("/api/customer-money/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator, string customerIsin)
    => mediator.Send(new GetMoneyQuery(customerIsin)));
app.MapGet("/api/customer-portfolio/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator, string customerIsin)
    => mediator.Send(new GetPortfolioQuery(customerIsin)));
app.MapGet("/api/customer-order/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator, string customerIsin)
    => mediator.Send(new GetOrdersQuery(customerIsin)));
app.MapPost("/api/add-order/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator, AddOrderCommand cmd)
    => mediator.Send(cmd));
app.MapDelete("/api/delete-order/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator, [FromBody] DeleteOrderCommand cmd)
    => mediator.Send(cmd));
app.MapPut("/api/modify-order/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator,[FromBody] ModifyOrderCommand cmd)
    => mediator.Send(cmd));

app.Run();
```

Two teams want to use these API's; the first team needs to use 3 of them and the second team needs others, and the teams shouldn't access others team's API's.

I was thinking about creating an env in `appsettings.json`.

Would you please let me know if there is a better solution?

Comment: _"and the teams shouldn't access others team's API's."_ - seems like you should implement some kind of authorization.

Comment: TBH I don't fully understand. What will prevent the second team from hitting service deployed with `EnableOrderCRUD`?

Comment: I define a variable inside appsetting if I set it to false the second team can't access these api's

Comment: Teams will have separate deployments?

Comment: @GuruStron Yes exactly,we deploy the service in 2 pods with different Env config

Answer (score 0):

My final solution :

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter : IEndpointFilter
{
    private readonly OrderOptions _option;
    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(IOptions<OrderOptions> options)
    {
        _option= options.Value;
    }
    public async ValueTask<object?> InvokeAsync(EndpointFilterInvocationContext context, EndpointFilterDelegate next)
    {
        if (_option.EnableOrderCRUD) return await next(context);
        return Results.Problem("You don't currently have permission to access this object's");
    }


}
public record OrderOptions
{
    public bool EnableOrderCRUD { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
app.MapPut("/api/modify-order/", ([FromServices] IMediator mediator,[FromBody] ModifyOrderCommand cmd)
    => mediator.Send(cmd)).AddEndpointFilter<CustomAuthenticationFilter>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that authorization would make more sense if the service was deployed as shared one (i.e. the same instance(s) would be used by both teams), then you would employ the standard approach by providing access tokens to both of the teams and restricting the access based on some authorization rules.

Since you have decided to solve this "infrastructurally" (unless you want explicit 401 Unauthorized) i.e. by deploying different instances of the service for different teams I would solve this by just not mapping the endpoints based on settings. Something along these lines:

```cs
// map "shared" endpoints

var opts = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<OrderOptions>>();

if(opts.Value.EnableOrderCRUD)
{
   // map "non-shared" ones:
   app.MapPut("/api/modify-order/", ...);
   // ...
}
```